# TFS to Release Management - Release from Build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I am so close yet so far from getting my Visual Studio (MVC) application released through TFS & Release Management. I am using Version 2013 and have my build definition setup as follows:

[image: Build Definition]

As you can see it is using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml as its template, and as such I cannot see the options for Release as I have been finding in all other examples online - eg:

[image]

I have gone into Release Management and setup my Release Template to reference this build definition and selected 'Can Trigger a Release from a Build'... but I have nothing happen in RM when I Build in Visual Studio.

What I have also found is that because the application I am building is MVC with Windows Authentication - every time I run a manual release, the Web Site gets rebuilt (as per my release template), but the website is always rebuilt with Windows Authentication Disabled... Which is a pain as I keep having to go into IIS after every release to enable Windows Authentication.

So, my questions are...

1) What am I doing wrong with my version of the Build Definition setup that it will not prompt a release?

2) Do I have to Remove and Create my website on the Release Template... and if so...

3) How do I get around the fact I always have to revisit IIS to enable Windows Authentication after each release?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the vNext release template?

Comment: No, its the Agent-Based Release Template... I haven't looked at the vNext options.

Answer (score 4):

You need to switch your build template to ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml.

You can find that file in the folder:
Program Files (x86)\ Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReleaseManagement\bin

You need to check that into your TFS repo, then switch your build definition over to use it.https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181355(v=vs.120).aspx#add_template

Comment: Also worth noting that you need to install and configure the RM client on the build server

Comment: Thanks for the advice... Managed to crack the nut just before I left the office yesterday...! Appreciate the feedback though as the link is very handy. One of few pages I didnt actually find when investigating!??!